# SVG Animation, Layers, and Rendering Order

Tags: animation, svg

So I have an SVG that goes something like this:

```
<svg>

<g id='leftArm'>
  <shapes for upper arm>
  <circle id='leftShoulderPivot' />
  <g id="leftForearm'>
    <shapes for lower arm>
    <circle id='leftElbowPivot' />
    <circle id='leftWristPivot' />
    <g id='leftHand'>
        <shapes for left hand>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>

<g id='torso'>
  <shapes>
</g>

</svg>
```

This allows me to rotate the arm, forearm, and hand groups using the cx and cy vales of the appropriate pivots as the rotation origin.  Hooray!

However, I would like the forearm shapes to render beneath the torso shapes and the hand shapes to render on top of the torso shapes.  As is, when you rotate the arms down, the hands go behind the torso.

So I'm looking for one of two solutions:

a) a way to shift the rendering order of the existing SVG so forearms render first and hands render last

b) a way to move the hands groups out of the arm groups while still keeping the hands group's x,y, and rotation equal to the wrist pivot

Ideally I'd like to do this within the SVG and not rely on outside javascript.  I could write javascript that fixes the hand's position whenever other javascript moves the arms, but then I would not be able to use SVG animation for "idle animation" loops and the like.

Thank you!

Comment: Use multiple groups and apply the same transformations to each group.

Comment: consider moving the pivots down the stack ... so the wrist pivot is on the hand.

Comment: Robert, that sounds like it would work! Basically have a "back arms" group and a "front arms" group, the torso in between, with the actual shapes for the arms in the back arms and the shapes for the hands in the front group.  Sounds perfect, thanks!

Comment: And yes, implemented, works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea should work ... as seen below. Will not work in IE.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200" height="200">
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
path {fill: none; stroke: #000; stroke-width:.2;}
rect {fill: #999;}

#human {
  animation: sway 2s ease alternate infinite;
}

#arm-left-upper {
  animation: upanddown 4s ease alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#arm-left-lower {
  animation: upanddown 3s ease alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#arm-left-hand {
  animation: wave 1s ease alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

@keyframes sway {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); } 
  100% { transform: translateX(2px); } 
}

@keyframes upanddown {
  0% { transform: rotate(-30deg) } 
  100% { transform: rotate(30deg); } 
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% { transform: rotate(-80deg) } 
  100% { transform: rotate(20deg); } 
}
</style>
</defs>

  <g id="human">

    <g id="arm-left">
      <g id="arm-left-upper">
        <path d="M4 2l1 1"/>

        <g id="arm-left-lower">
          <path d="M5 3v1"/>

          <g id="arm-left-hand">
            <path d="M5 4h-.3"/>
          </g>
        </g>

      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="torso">
      <rect x="2" y="1.8" width="2" height="3"/>
    </g>

  </g>


</svg>
```

Comment: Ah, mis-read question ... you want hand in front and fore-arms behind torso ... hmm